# Switch submodule URL with different commits results in "not a tree"

Tags: git, git-submodules

I need to switch a submodule of a project with one I created. The new submodule is in a repo I own.

1. I forked the main project repo.
2. I modified the `.gitmodules` file with the URL of the new repo submodule (my repo).
3. I did `git submodule sync`.
4. I did `git submodule init`.
5. I did `git submodule update --recusrsive`.

It worked file for all the submodules not modified, but for the submodule I modified it returns:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: 3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed
```

This is because the main repo is already pointing at the commit `3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed` of the original submodule, but in my submodule there is not such commit.

Where is that commit pointer stored and why does submodule work like that? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

> Where is that commit pointer stored ...

There are two copies:

- One is permanently frozen into a *commit* in the superproject.  That is, the superproject commit itself says, to anyone who reads the commit: *This commit shall be used with submodule commit `3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed`.*  Obviously this commit only works, as a whole, if submodule commit `3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed` exists; but since all commits are completely read-only, this superproject commit will say that forever (or for as long as the superproject commit continues to exist).  Since you can't change it, you might as well not worry about it.

  The entry in your superproject commit is called a *gitlink*.
- The other copy is in your *index*.  It probably got there by being copied from the commit, to your index.  The index is also called the *staging area* and this index / staging-area has a copy of *every* file from the commit.  That is, you did something—probably, ran `git checkout`—that told Git to extract some superproject commit.  That superproject commit contains lots of files, e.g., `README.md`, `.gitmodules`, and so on.  It also contains the gitlink entry saying that submodule X should do a `git checkout 3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed`.

  When Git did a checkout of all of those files (`README.md`, `.gitmodules`, etc.), it copied them to your index and to your work-tree.  It also copied the gitlink to your index.  So the gitlink `3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed` is now in your index under the submodule path, and `git submodule update` will enter the submodule and run `git checkout 3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed`.

The index gitlink is the one you need to change.  To change it, enter the submodule yourself—manually—and `git checkout` the commit you'd like your index to name.  Then exit the submodule, returning to the superproject, and run `git add path/to/submodule`.  That will copy the commit hash that *is* checked out in the submodule, into the gitlink entry in your index.

Since Git makes all *new* commits from whatever is in the index *at the time you run `git commit`*, you're now ready to make a new commit that's a whole lot like the previous commit—it has the same `README.md` and `.gitmodules` and so on—except that it has the gitlink that you want instead of the old `3062d287c322fabf1b41b8e33518eb449d4ac6ed` one.  You can, of course, `git add` more things to copy them from your work-tree into your index before committing: e.g., maybe you made a URL change to `.gitmodules` in your work-tree that you'd like to put into the new commit too.

There are other ways to change the gitlink in your index, but the method above is perhaps the most straightforward one, since you can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the explanation. I don't completely like the answer because it requires to have the submodule in the pc, while I'd like to cleanly make it download at the correct path by "git submodule (update)". 
If I have the submodule already downloaded I can also simply checkout the submodule, then commit and the gitlink of the superproject will already point at the new correct commit.

Comment: If you know the right hash ID, you can use `git update-index` to stuff it in to your index as an updated gitlink (mode `160000`, I think), but that's incredibly error-prone. Note, though, that just going into the submodule (if you have it in your work-tree) and checking out the right commit is *not* sufficient: the gitlink entry in the superproject index remains unchanged.